Control optimization in V8's TurboFan
I'm studying some internals of V8's TurboFan and came across this slide:
Original slide.
This diagram shows a branch that is removed during control optimization, resulting in a direct connection to a "Dead" node. However, the nodes x and y are not eliminated during this process.
Why are the nodes x and y retained after control reduction? Shouldn't they be removed as well since they seem to be part of the dead code?

The slide shows an intermediate step. Nodes depending on dead control will be removed.
